# Parsing complex xml to java using jaxb

Tags: jaxb

Can anyone suggest a piece of code, for converting xml to java using jaxb.
My xml file look like

```
     <Customer>
    <Operation>Sample</Operation>
    <head>
        <sub>
            <value>
                <att>
                    <req>
                        <name>sample</name>
                        <value>
                            <string> sample values </string>
                        </value>
                    </req>
                </att>
            </value>
        </sub>
        <sub>
            <value>
                <att>
                    <req>
                        <name>var</name>
                        <value>
                            <string>var value</string>
                        </value>
                    </req>
                </att>
            </value>
        </sub>
    </head>
</Customer>
```

I used the following piece of code, but i am getting null values

```
File file = new File("C:\\xml.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(customer.name);
System.out.println(customer.string);
```

My expected output should be like

```
Sample
sample values
var
var value
```

Comment: You may be interested in the following:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html

Answer (score 0):

How can i get multiple value by same tag name. For example if the xml is like

Xml file

```
   <customer>
      <sample>
      <name>name</name>
      <value>
      <string> value </string>
      </value> 
      </sample>
      <sample>
      <name>name</name>
      <value>
      <string> value </string>
      </value> 
      </sample>
</customer>
```

I am using following code

```
File file = new File("C:\\sample.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Customer customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
System.out.println(customer.value.string);
System.out.println(customer.sample.name);
```